# joinしたテーブルに対して、特定のカラムの検索条件がない場合は、同じカラムへの違う条件で検索したい

Tags: mysql, sql

以下のような二つのテーブルが存在します。

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(255) ,
  `geo_latitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'スポット緯度',
  `geo_longitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'スポット経度',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tableA_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `language_code_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tableA_id) REFERENCES tableA (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

tableAとtableBの関係は、tableAが基本となる情報を保持しているのですが、このtabelAの多言語の情報をtableBが保持するようになっています。また、tabelAが保持するtableBの多言語情報は基本的に不定なのですが、日本語(languagecode=1)は必ず持つような作りになっています。

このような状況の中で、特定の緯度経度から近い物を検索して、指定された言語コードのvalueを取得,
もし指定の言語がなければ日本語を取得するというsqlを実行したいです。
現状緯度経度部分のsqlはかけているのですが、”指定された言語コードのvalueを取得,
もし指定の言語がなければ日本語を取得”という部分のクエリがかけていないです。

ご教授いただけると幸いです。
ちなみに環境はMySQLです。
--現状のクエリ--

```
SELECT 
tableA.id, tableA.uuid, geo_latitude AS latitude, geo_longitude AS longitude, ( 6371000 * acos( cos(radians(35.730)) * cos(radians(geo_latitude)) * cos(radians(geo_longitude) - radians(139.831)) + sin(radians(35.730)) * sin(radians(geo_latitude)) ) ) AS distance, 
`tableB`.`language_code_id`, `tableB`.`value`
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN `tableB` ON tableA.id = `tableB`.`tableA_id`
HAVING distance <= 100.0 
ORDER BY distance;
```

--tableAテストデータ---

```
INSERT INTO `tableA` (`id`, `uuid`, `geo_latitude`, `geo_longitude`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
(1,'f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba08',35.730,139.830,'2019-04-17 11:47:49','2019-04-17 11:47:49'),
(2,'f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba09',35.7301,139.8301,'2019-04-17 11:47:49','2019-04-17 11:47:49'),
(3,'f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba10',35.7302,139.8302,'2019-04-17 11:47:49','2019-04-17 11:47:49'),
(4,'f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba11',35.7303,139.8303,'2019-04-17 11:47:49','2019-04-17 11:47:49'),
(5,'f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba11',35.734,139.834,'2019-04-17 11:47:49','2019-04-17 11:47:49');
```

--tableBテストデータ--

```
INSERT INTO `tableB` (`id`, `tableA_id`, `language_code_id`, `value`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1,'テストデータ1_日本語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (2,1,2,'テストデータ1_英語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (3,1,3,'テストデータ1_中国語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (4,2,1,'テストデータ2_日本語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (5,2,2,'テストデータ2_英語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (6,3,1,'テストデータ3_日本語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (7,4,1,'テストデータ4_日本語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (8,4,2,'テストデータ4_英語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (9,4,3,'テストデータ4_中国語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (10,4,4,'テストデータ4_韓国語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (11,5,1,'テストデータ5_日本語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00'),
    (12,5,4,'テストデータ5_韓国語','2019-04-17 11:49:00','2019-04-17 11:49:00');
```

-- language_code_id対応表 ---
id 言語
1  日本語
2  英語
3  中国語
4  韓国語
5  タイ語

上記のテストデータの場合、やりたいことは
条件は35.730,139.830の地点より100m以内にあるもの
取得したいデータは
tableAの各カラムと、検索地点からの取得データまでの距離、
tableBのvalueなのですが、中国語のvalueが欲しいのだけれど、中国語がない場合は日本語が欲しい。
という事になります。

この場合取得したいデータ(tableAの各カラムは省略しています)は
tableA.id, tableB.language_code_id, tableB.value
1, 3, 'テストデータ1_中国語'
2, 1, 'テストデータ2_日本語'
3, 1, 'テストデータ3_日本語'
4, 3, 'テストデータ4_中国語'
になります。

Comment: having distance の値はtableAの内容のみでフィルターがされていますが、"指定の言語がなければ日本語を取得"した場合の tableA.id, tableA.uuid, latitude, longitude, distanceはどういった情報がほしいですか？

Comment: 可能であれば、テストデータや、求める結果を質問文に含めていただけると、回答しやすいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問内容編集したのですが、これでいかがでしょうか？すいませんがご助力いただけると助かります。

Comment: Tanokura はい、大丈夫です。また、更新して頂いたテストデータから取得されるべき結果等もあればカンペキだと思います。:)
また、language_code_id に対応する表もありますか？
id: 1, language_name: 日本語, id: 2, language_name: 中国語 のようなものです。

Comment: Daichi 質問の編集ありがとうございます。対応表と取得したいデータ結果追加しました。テストデータも一部修正いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

改善できるクエリだと思いますが、一応やりたい事は機能しているようなので、回答します。

```
SELECT 
  tableA.id,
  tableA.uuid,
  tableA.geo_latitude AS latitude,
  geo_longitude AS longitude, 
  ( 6371000 * acos( cos(radians(35.730)) * cos(radians(geo_latitude)) * cos(radians(geo_longitude) - radians(139.831)) + sin(radians(35.730)) * sin(radians(geo_latitude)) ) ) AS distance,
  IFNULL(tableB_selected_by_language_code.language_code_id, 1) as selected_language_code_id,
  (SELECT value from tableB where tableA_id = tableA.id and language_code_id = selected_language_code_id LIMIT 1)
FROM 
  tableA
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECt tableA_id, language_code_id from tableB where language_code_id = 3) as tableB_selected_by_language_code ON tableA.id = tableB_selected_by_language_code.tableA_id
HAVING 
  distance <= 100.0;
```

結果

```
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | uuid                                 | latitude   | longitude   | distance          | selected_language_code_id | (SELECT value from tableB where tableA_id = tableA.id and language_code_id = selected_language_code_id LIMIT 1) |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba08 | 35.7300000 | 139.8300000 | 90.26559759844687 |                         3 | テストデータ1_中国語                                                                                            |
|  2 | f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba09 | 35.7301000 | 139.8301000 | 81.99640330604278 |                         1 | テストデータ2_日本語                                                                                            |
|  3 | f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba10 | 35.7302000 | 139.8302000 | 75.55925354368239 |                         1 | テストデータ3_日本語                                                                                            |
|  4 | f4975f27-e07a-4389-b615-a566fa66ba11 | 35.7303000 | 139.8303000 | 71.45090627299126 |                         3 | テストデータ4_中国語                                                                                            |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

変更点は３箇所です。
 1. LEFT JOIN
LEFT JOIN を使うことで、指定したlanguage_code_idが無い場合、NULLで結合するようにしています。
 2. IFNULL
NULLで結合されたカラムに対して、DEFAULTとしてlanguage_code_id = 1(日本)を設定します
 3. SELECT value ...
DEFAULTが１となる抽出されたlanguage_code_idを使って、valueを取得

また、tableBには tableA_id と language_code_idに対して 複合UNIQUE制約をつけたほうがいいです。(でない場合、LIMIT 1で返る値が変わる可能性があります)

CASE WHENを使っての抽出もできるとは思います。

今回のSQLですが、コードで使うなら、シンプルなクエリを２つ実行したほうがわかりやすいかもしれません。

Comment: 丁寧に解説までつけていただけありがとうございます。IFNULLでDEFAUL値を設定する発想が全くなかったので勉強になりました。重ね重ねありがとうございました。

Comment: @YuukiTanokura 大丈夫であれば、回答の承認オネガイシマス